# Cannot delete only one json item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am dealing with the problem. I want to delete JSON item only by found attribute, here is Json:

```
{"name": "Nike shirt", "price": "20", "size": "M", "additionalInfo": "best shirt ever", "gender": "male", "itemType": "shirts"}
{"name": "adidas airmax", "price": "30", "size": "40", "additionalInfo": "best shoe ever", "gender": "male", "itemType": "running shoes"}
```

Here is delete method:

```
@staticmethod
def deleteFromCart(cartJson,searchAttribute):
        for item in Item.jsonOpener(cartJson):
            if(item.getName == searchAttribute):
                del item
        with open(cartJson, "w") as filelines: 
            for item in Item.jsonOpener(cartJson):               
                jsonString = json.dumps(item.__dict__)
                filelines.write(jsonString + "\n")
```

For example, I want to delete "Nike shirt" : Item.deleteFromCart("items.json","Nike Shirt") but it deletes me everything. Thank you for any answer.

I expect

```
{"name": "adidas airmax", "price": "30", "size": "40", "additionalInfo": "best shoe ever", "gender": "male", "itemType": "running shoes"}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: {"name": "adidas airmax", "price": "30", "size": "40", "additionalInfo": "best shoe ever", "gender": "male", "itemType": "running shoes"}

Comment: I have no idea what library you are using to handle the json, but I assume that `item.getName` is a method (because of how it is named), and I can tell that you are not actually calling the method.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read and write the same file **at the same time**:

```
with open(cartJson, "w") as filelines:  # here you open file for writing, which destroys contents
    for item in Item.jsonOpener(cartJson):  # and here you try to read the contents that no longer exist
```

You should first read the file into a variable, **then** open the file for writing and write the data back:

```
def deleteFromCart(cartJson,searchAttribute):
    data = []
    for item in Item.jsonOpener(cartJson):               
        if item.getName() != searchAttribute:
            # DON'T store the item you want deleted
            jsonString = json.dumps(item.__dict__)
            data.append(jsonString)
    with open(cartJson, "w") as filelines: 
        for line in data:
            filelines.write(line + "\n")
```